# To display the contents in Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

How can i display multiple images or texts in raspberry pi.Where i'm receiving these images and texts through the network which is being sent from another computer that is locally connected.

Comment: Raspberry Pi is a computer. You may want to use it or program it. This site is about programming. If you just want to show images from other computer I don't think you need to program anything. Showing images and texts from another computer is what many programs do, like web browsers or skype.

Comment: Please explain your application architecture and your raspberry pi setup. Have you connected a monitor or any other display device to raspberry pi? You can type the command startx to start the GUI on Pi. After that it works as any other linux system with minimum GUI. I can help you more if you could describe your scenario.

Comment: actually im planning to build a notice display system for college.notices are entered via web interface and its being send to Pi,from where it must be displayed to the monitor connected to Pi.So if multiple notices are being send i must display that too in a queue format one after other.

Comment: Since my college is locally connected over network,i can send my messages via ethernet ports to all RPi.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the pi, it is just a computer, do this the same way you would with any other linux computer.